# Reducing the size of a very large static library in Release builds

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015

We are working under Windows 7/10 and Visual Studio 2015, coding with C++ plus Qt (and linking with a handful other external libraries). Our project is rather big - more than 1300 classes, LOCs in the hundreds of thousands.

We now need to split up the project into a "core lib project" (to which our module test project links to) and a "main() project" (which also links with the lib project to produce the executable).

The issue I've run into is that that library created from the "core lib project" is gigantic - at least in release mode. Our application (when built in its current single-project form) ends up being ~40MB in size. The Library hits ~4GB(!) and then something breaks, because linking fails; the object file directory has ~7GB worth of .obj in it. (In debug mode the situation is far tamer - the library and .obj file directory do not exceed ~350MB). I'd appreciate any tips to what could cause this kind of size inflation (especially since the final all measure meagre ~40MB) or how to curtail it...

Update: I found the "culprit" for the inflated object file sizes - Visual Studio's "Full program optimization" - "link time code generation" (the option /LTCG) to be precise. I disabled LTCG and the object file size shrunk from 6.7GB total to 64MB total...

That said, I have less hope to reduce the library size since the linker during the creation of the library can probably not yet determine what it can optimize away (unlike during the creation of the final executable).

Comment: Are you still including debug information in your release compiles?  (Not the final .exe file, but having the compiler include the debug info in the .obj files.)

Comment: Do you mean around 40MiB for the *source*? That's is a *lot* of source code and will lead to quite a lot of binary code. And if you use templates that can inflate generated code size quite considerably.

Comment: This sounds wrong, debug builds, especially statically linked ones, are much larger than release builds. Are you sure you are not confusing the two?

Comment: @Some programmer dude The source is "only" ~26MB, if you exclude the auto-generated stuff (Qt generates quite a bit for forms and MOCs) The ~40MB is for the executable created by Debug mode (with the executable created by Release mode is smaller, around ~15MB)

Comment: @dtech Apologies, I was a bit unclear: The "Main() wrapper" and our "Module test project" are meant to link statically to the "Project_Core" library we want to create... Though I just now realize that we currently rely on mainly dynamic linkage (e.g. on Qt and most of our 3rd party libraries)...

Comment: That said, I doublechecked the size of both directories containing the generated object files (.obj) for "Debug" and "Release" ("Debug" /Od with Debug Information /Zi and "Release" /O2 without Debug Information) and the Debug clocks 377MB, while Release is at 6.7GB...

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I don't think so, but I'll double check. Is there any place beyond the "DebugInfomationFormat" setting (i.e. where you can e.g. set /Zi etc.) I could/should check?

Comment: Those numbers are consistent with the opposite scenario. A debug build cannot possibly be smaller than a release build, because it includes a tremendous amount of extra stuff. You may have some problems with the project settings or building.

Comment: @dtech I noticed that the Release build had LTCG enabled, but the Debug build did not. LTCG was responsible for inflating the Object size by two orders of magnitude; disabling it in Release resulted in a much smaller Object files (64MB total)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No wonder the statically linked binary is the shortest; unused object files are removed and most probably unused code inside the object files are excluded by the link optimizer.

I suspect excessive conditioning based on build mode. Did you play with _Debug macro and preprocessor directives?
What about project dependencies and linkage macros? Is the make file corrupt or not cautiously tampered with?

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, I'll look into that and tell you if I find anything.

Comment: "Full program optimization" i.e. "link time code generation" was the culprit, inflating the .obj files by two orders of magnitude. I turned it off for the time being, until we can split the library up further.

Comment: Good to know. But a factor of 10 is a little bit unusual. I guess more investigation on project management, you need. But code bloat is a probability in case of excessive template programming.